# JavaScript 'setInterval()' not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

If I just do `changeImage();` it works fine, but I can't figure out how to get `setInterval()` to work. Here's my code:

HTML:

```html
<div id="coin1"></div>
```

JS:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
  function changeImage() {
    if ($("#coin1").css("display") == "none") {  
      $("#coin1").fadeIn("slow");
    } else {  
      $("#coin1").fadeOut("slow");
    }
  };
  
  setInterval("changeImage()", 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're defining `changeImage()` within `$(document).ready()`, it isn't defined globally and therefore won't be called by setInterval. Use the function's name instead, i.e.:

```
setInterval(changeImage, 2000);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: that was the trick... I had just figured out that I could put the function outside of (document).ready(function() as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just to be crystal clear, as the accepted answer does show the correct code but the explanation is incorrect, the issue is not that:

> ...you're defining `changeImage()` within `$(document).ready()`...

It is completely fine for you to define functions within the scope of `$(document).ready()`.

The issue is that you're passing a string – `setInterval("changeImage()", 2000);` – as the first parameter to `setInterval()` instead of a function to be used as the callback. Per the accepted answer's code (but not explanation), the proper way to use `setInterval()` is like `setInterval(changeImage, 2000);`. Notice that parentheses are not used here. This is because you want to pass the function itself as the parameter, not whatever is returned by the function when it's called.

The only reason the code you're using happens to work when you move it outside of the scope of `$(document).ready()` is because when you do pass a string, the interpreter is forced to run an `eval()` against the string, and the `eval()` is happening in the global scope.

So while it is *possible* to have the solution work with a string, it is not good coding. Per [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) for `setInterval()`:

> An optional syntax allows you to include a string instead of a function, which is compiled and executed every delay milliseconds. This syntax is *not recommended* for the same reasons that make using `eval()` a security risk.